# pymodes Modeslive throws ValueError: ctypes objects containing pointers cannot be pickled

Tags: multiprocessing, decode, rtl-sdr, pyrtlsdr

Windows 10
Python 3.11.8
In PyCharm environment:
pip list

```
`Package        Version
-------------- -------
numpy          1.26.4
pip            23.2.1
pymodes        2.17
pyrtlsdr       0.3.0
pyrtlsdrlib    0.0.2
pyzmq          24.0.1
setuptools     68.2.0
wheel          0.41.2
windows-curses 2.3.2`
```

Hello,
When trying to get modeslive running, I get following error:

```
`  File "E:\JetBrains\PycharmProjects\Diplomarbeit_Radar_im-Eigenheim\.venv\Scripts\modeslive.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "E:\JetBrains\PycharmProjects\Diplomarbeit_Radar_im-Eigenheim\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyModeS\streamer\modeslive.py", line 139, in main
    recv_process.start()
  File "E:\Python\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 121, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Python\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 224, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Python\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 336, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "E:\Python\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 95, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "E:\Python\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
ValueError: ctypes objects containing pointers cannot be pickled`
```

How can I further track the issue?
Thank you.

I cannot get pymodes to work. Why do I get this error?
I tried with python 3.8 to 3.11, only install pymodes and librtlsrd and constantly get this error. What am I doing wrong?
(On the side, I have dump1090 with my rtlsrd working perfectly. So that's not that part of the set up.)
The error seems so pythonic that I cannot conceive that someone else does not bump into this.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].